# Custom MembershipProvider SharePoint FBA and the user's display name

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider, peoplepicker

we are using both windows authentication and forms based authentication in a claims aware SharePoint WebApplication. The custom MembershipProvider (datasource: Novell eDirectory) works just fine but I'm uncertain about a few things.

**The cn property of each user record is a unique identifier (hexadecimal value).
Users are logging in using their email addresses** (and password) **though**. We don't want to make the unique identifier visible anywhere.

```cs
GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
FindUsersByEmail(...) and
FindUsersByName(...)
```

return MembershipUser(s) which are constructed this way:

```cs
CustomMembershipUser membershipUser = new CustomMembershipUser(
            providerName: Name, // the membership provider's name
            userName: providerUserKey, *// the "cn" name*
            providerUserKey: providerUserKey, *// again the "cn" name*
            email: email, // the email used to log in
            passwordQuestion: null,
            comment: null,
            isApproved: true,
            isLockedOut: false,
            creationDate: DateTime.MinValue,
            lastLoginDate: DateTime.MinValue,
            lastActivityDate: DateTime.MinValue,
            lastPasswordChangedDate: DateTime.MinValue,
            lastLockedOutDate: DateTime.MinValue,
            firstName: givenName,
            lastName: surName);
```

The last two parameters are "Custom-"MembershipUser parameters. ***My ultimate goal is to display users in an Windows-Integrated-Authentication-style "LastName, FirstName".***

Right now upon entering my email address the people picker resolves my email address to a "cn" name which is something like XYZ12345. Instead I want to display "LastName, FirstName" throughout SharePoint. The information is present in the datasource (eDirectory) and I can enrich my CustomMembershipUser with this information but of course neither the PeoplePicker nor anything else in SharePoint will be aware of my custom MembershipUser.

Is there anything claims related I should be aware of?

Comment: Are email addresses guaranteed to be unique in Novell eDirectory? If so, just change userName: providerUserKey to userName: email in your constructor. It wouldn't get you to Last Name, First Name, but would be better than cn.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing right now.
I'll investigate using User Profile Service now.